# Why do we need a small external gate to source capacitor for a MOSFET drive circuit?

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, gate-driving

I have a question regarding a MOSFET half bridge driver circuit. We always connect a small capcitor between the gate and source of both the high side and the low side switch, typically in picofarads. I searched to see why it is used.  The answer I have found is to reduce or compensate the effect of internal gate to source Cgs of MOSFET in order to achieve optimum switching performance.

I need a bit of explanation to understand how exactly it compensate the Cgs. Does this Cgs external have some impact on the Miller plateau as well?

Comment: Here are some MOSFET-related search terms for you to build a background: "shoot through", "dead time", "parasitic turn on".

Comment: @Alison Can you post a schematic example? There is a circuit tool if you edit the question.

Comment: @VoltageSpike It's probably in reference to the schematic in their previous question, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691903/optimization-of-gate-resistance-value-for-gate-driver-circut-of-a-sic-mosfet but if OP could clarify, that would be helpful.